# Delete rows based on condition and keep e-mails

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe that have to contain only e-mails:

```
email
1   jquery@3.5                         #it is not an e-mail so delete it
2   amministrazione@edilportale.com    #it is a a e-mail so keep it
3   258x530@2x.png                     #it is not an e-mail so delete it
4   secco@2x.png                       #...
```

How can i delete these rows that aren't e-mail?
Maybe based on a condition that if the next value after the point (.) is a number or a .png (or other type image) delete, how to achive this? do you have a better solution ?

Update:

This is the condition i used for scrap them:

```
mail_list = re.findall('\w+@\w+\.{1}\w+', html_text)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete all records with invalid email. Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68754815/delete-all-records-with-invalid-email-pandas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the regex like:

```
df2 = df[df['email'].str.contains(r'^[a-z0-9]+[\._]?[a-z0-9]+[@]\w+[.]\w{2,3}$' , regex = True)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Only you know the specific selection condition but assuming @ is followed by a non-digit you could use:

```
df2 = df[df['email'].str.contains(r'@\D', regex = True)]
```